# Python Speech Recognition: AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'record'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, spyder

I'm getting this error 'AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'record'' in the below code.  It is not because my filename is Speech_Recognition, i've tried that bug fix.  Any ideas?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio as pa
import time as t

mic = sr.Microphone()

inp = sr.AudioFile('data.wav')
with inp as source:
    audio = sr.record(source)
```

Comment: Run this with `python -v` and provide the output. It will contain more infromation about module import.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another variable:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
```

Then change `sr.record(source)` to `r.record(source)`

I hope this helped!